# Does posts_per_page prevent a full scan of posts table?

Tags: database, wordpress

I'm trying to prevent the full scan of the wp_post table with 100K+ records on our homepage. I only want the first 30 with no pagination.

If I'm not using pagination, and using post_per_page to limit the query does it still scan the whole table and then return the first 30 or does it go from row 1 to 30 then stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress loop executed, while loading any template, scans only once with defined limit. This limit is defined in *Settings > Reading*.

Whereas, if you are using `post_per_page` with `query_posts` then it will re-execute the query. It is not recommended for large websites.
Refer: Additional SQL Queries section [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).